# Newline character doesn't render in browser

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

Why does the below code displays new line in console, but not in the browser/database? How can I resolve this?

```
StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder("John"); 
s2.append("Hey" + "\n")
```

Please assume that this code snippet is a part of the bigger code that is saving the conversation in a database.

Comment: How did you send it to the browser? You need to replace all "\n" with "</br>".

Comment: Note that just a single newline is not platform independent either. Most applications will treat it as end of line nowadays, but generally you want to use the platform default if printing text to a console (e.g. `String.format("%n")`).

Comment: For java \n is the newline character, but browsers its the break tag <br>

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace `"\n"` with `"<br/>"` before sending to browser.

Also, you can probably add css `style="white-space: pre-line"` to the html component if you don't want the server side conversion. I haven't tested this solution myself.

Answer (score 1):

It's because newline characters are normally interpreted by HTML as spaces. The usual way to have the text start on the next line in HTML is via a
tag.

(If the text is enclosed in a  element then newline characters are interpreted as new line instructions, but  does other things which might be inconsistent with what you want the page to look like.)

Comment: New line characters are NOT treated as spaces. They are simply ignored.